# Linear Growth Model

Tags: functions, inverse

I have a problem where I have been given that $r(t)=at+b, 0 \leq t \leq \frac{100-b}{a}$. I have then been asked to find $t(r)$. Is this simply finding the inverse of $r(t)$?

Comment: Yes, that is what is meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed. That would be (spoiler alert) :

$$t(r) = (r-b)/a$$

Comment: That's what I got - a pretty easy inverse to compute. I had just never seen it written in that notation versus inverse notation.

Comment: Yes it can be annoying if the question is not very clear, but in your case (I guess) there shouldn't have been any source of confusion